# Split a string having multiple delimeters using shell script

Tags: shell, csv, split

````
```
````

I have a string in the below format
aYbMTcDdHeMfs
where a,b,c,d,e and f are numerics of any length.
Y-> Years
MT-> Months
D-> days
H-> hours
M-> minutes
S-> Seconds

````
```

The string can have anything like

1H2M3S
1Y2MT3D4H5H6S
1Y20S 
.. so on.


Here the input has the same order of years,months,days,hours,minutes and seconds.

    If we want to fetch the value of years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds from the string then what would be the shell script to convert it into seconds?
    
    1H20S -> 3620
    
    10M200S -> 800
    
    10M100S -> 700
````

Can you help me with the script to find those?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What shell are you targeting? Basic POSIX sh?

Comment: And how do you get 3620 *years* from 1H20S? Did you mean seconds?

Comment: What does it mean to convert MT into seconds? February has fewer seconds than July, for example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specification is incomplete but here's a couple of ideas to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
aYbMTcDdHeMfS(){
    x=${1//Y/*31536000+}
    x=${x//MT/*2628000+}
    x=${x//D/*86400+}
    x=${x//H/*3600+}
    x=${x//M/*60+}
    x=${x//S/+}
    x=${x%+}
    echo "$((x))"
}

aYbMTcDdHeMfS            1H  # 3600
aYbMTcDdHeMfS         15S3M  # 195
aYbMTcDdHeMfS        1H2M3S  # 3723
aYbMTcDdHeMfS 1Y2MT3D4H5H6S  # 37083606
aYbMTcDdHeMfS         1Y20S  # 31536020
aYbMTcDdHeMfS         1H20S  # 3620
aYbMTcDdHeMfS       10M200S  # 800
aYbMTcDdHeMfS       10M100S  # 700
```

```
<<'EOD' sed '
    s/[[:space:]]*//g
    s/Y/*31536000+/g
    s/MT/*2628000+/g
    s/D/*86400+/g
    s/H/*3600+/g
    s/M/*60+/g
    s/S/+/g
    s/+*$//
' | bc -l
1H
15S3M
1H2M3S
1Y2MT3D4H5H6S
1Y20S
1H20S
10M200S
10M100S
EOD
```

Comment: Here the string can be anything of:

[aY][bM][cD][TdHeMfS]

In this case the above function doesn't work for aD